# Calculating averages with inputted numbers using for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate an average of the numbers that are inputted following the "Enter the number" part. I don't know how to add the inputted numbers as they aren't set variables. When I run it, it says 'int object is not iterable'

I thought about asking for each number separately, but I wouldn't know how to make it repeat the set number of times for each time the question is asked. So I use the for loop, but by using the for loop, I can't set numbers to variables, so I can't add them.
Apparently sum function can help, but nothing I've looked at shows me how to use it very well.

```
how_many = int(input("How many numbers are there?"))
for counter in range (1, (how_many + 1)):
    numbers = int(input("Enter number:"))
    sum1 = sum(numbers)
    av = sum1 / how_many
```

The result of the code is supposed to show the average of the numbers inputted but I can't figure out how to work out the total?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
how_many = int(input("How many numbers are there?"))
total_sum=0
for counter in range (1, (how_many + 1)):
    number = int(input("Enter number:"))
    total_sum = total_sum+number
avg = total_sum / how_many
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sum` calculates the total in an `iterable`, eg `list`.

If we loop, and add the number to a list each time, we can calculate the average at the end.

This should do the trick:

```
how_many = int(input("How many numbers are there?"))

numbers = []
for counter in range (how_many):
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter number:")))


total = sum(numbers)
av = total / how_many

print("Average:", av)
```

Output:

```
How many numbers are there?5
Enter number:1
Enter number:2
Enter number:3
Enter number:4
Enter number:5
Average: 3.0
```

Comment: @let's_go if you found any of these answers correct and useful, please mark the answer as accepted :)